# Cocos2d - 4inch screen displace the game

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i developed a game for the iphone4. Now i got problems with the iphone5 and the 4inch screen. My game is on the left side of the 4inch screen and i have a big black border on the right side. But the buttons from the game are in the middle of screen, they have same position like on the iphone4. I checked everythin but i dont know why the background-images and the sprites are on the left side and the buttons are in the middle. I want that everything is in the middle or on the left side. It would be great if anybody could help me!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**COCOS2d-iPhone:**

> If you're using the latest beta, the only change you should need to
>   make is export all your images at twice the size and use the "-hd"
>   suffix, similar to Apple's "@2x". The documentation also says you need
>   to set the content scale factor of the director.

You can find the documentation [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3ahow_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d).

and more detail [here](http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Developing+for+Multiple+Screen+Resolutions).

**COCS2d-X:**

Cocos2D-x has a very easy solution for multi-resolution problem.

In fact you just need to set your `DesignResolution` and then just imagine your target device will has this resolution.

If target device really has this resolution ( or some other but with same ratio) cocos2d will handle to fix screen and your game looks same in all devices.

And when ratio of target device is different, you have many option ( as cocos2d language, `policy`) to manage that.

For example if you use `Exact fit` policy, cocos2d will force your game ( and design) to fit target device screen (without that black boarder).

> Exact fit
>
> The entire application is visible in the specified area without trying
>   to preserve the original aspect ratio. Distortion can occur, and the
>   application may appear stretched or compressed.

For more detail just take a look at this link : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Multi_resolution_support

Comment: Although the link is for cocos2d-x community, There are exact same functions available for objective-c.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Can you tell me how i can set DesignResolution in cocos2d? In cocos documentation i can´t find setDesignResolution! Is it an adjustment in the appDelegate?!

Comment: Thank you again!! I don´t use the latest version of cocos2d. But the resolution of graphics is not the problem!! The problem is, that the background-image is on the left side on the 4 inch screen and the buttons are in the middle. On the iPhone3 and 4 it works fine. I want that everything (Button and Background-image) is on left side or in the middle of the screen. You can see my problem here http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~tobias83/Screens/Screens.pdf
The code is on the second site. It would be great if you can help me again. Thanks